# When would casting 'this' be required?

Tags: java, casting, this

Are there any situations in Java that would require you to explicitly cast `this` to another type other than the current class?

```
class SomeClass
{
    void foo()
    {
        SomeOtherClass s = (SomeOtherClass) this;
    }
}
```

***EDIT***: All answers refer to situations where `SomeOtherClass` is a sub-class of `SomeClass`, but casting `this` can be avoided in these situations with proper OO design. I am looking for situations where OO can't help you out, i.e. where `SomeOtherClass` is a **super**-class of `SomeClass`.

Comment: Now you got it the wrong way around. If `SomeOtherClass` is a super-class of `SomeClass`, then you have not to cast (since you are going up the hierachy). You have to cast, if `SomeOtherClass` is a sub-class of `SomeClass`. And I think your design is faulty, if you have to do things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only narrowing casts and widening casts. Narrowing casts will cast to a subtype or an `interface` type, which the current type does not declare to implement. As you said yourself, you should always be able to avoid the necessity of such a cast with a proper OO design.

Applying widening cast to `this` should also be unnecessary given the fact, that a reference type inherits all members of its superclass, with the exception of `static` members, which are not accessed via `this` anyway, and `private` members, which can’t be accessed even with a cast. The only scenario where a widening cast of `this` might be useful is to access a field which has been hidden by another field of the same name:

```
class A {
    int foo;
}
class B extends A {
    int foo;
}
class C extends B {
    {
        ((A)this).foo=42;
    }
}
```

Note that within `B` a simple `super.foo=42;` would be sufficient, only `C` requires a type conversion to access `A.foo`. And, of course, you can avoid every widening cast by the introduction of a variable of that type, as assigning to it makes the widening conversion implicit:

```
A tmp=this;
tmp.foo=42;
```

Another scenario might be that you want to call an overloaded method passing `this` as an argument, but want to select the overload which accepts a broader type or have to select one because otherwise it’s ambiguous. Still, this can be solved with an additional variable without a type cast.

So, applying a type cast to `this` should *always* be avoidable.

Nevertheless, I’m not sure whether every developer strives for the “proper OO design” in every code (s)he writes. Further, a developer might prefer a widening type cast over a temporary variable sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

When SomeClass is a super-class of the SomeOtherClass. But then... if you do this, it means something is not quite right with your OO design, you're abusing your model, most probably.

Comment: Since `this` is of type `SomeOtherClass`, one would not have to cast it explicitly.

Comment: @Turing85 this is of type SomeClass

Comment: @peter.petrov Yes. And `SomeOtherClass`, since it inherits from `SomeOtherClass` (at least in the sense of `instanceof`). My point is: you do not have to cast it explicitly.

Comment: Guys, think about it some more. You don't need a cast if it was the other way around.

Comment: @peter.petrov Point taken. Stupid me.

Comment: But are there situations where you need an explicit cast if `SomeClass <: SomeOtherClass`?

Comment: @Clashsoft Sorry, not sure what this notation `<:` means.

Comment: *{How dare you!}* SomeClass is a sub-class of SomeOtherClass

Comment: Well, OK, if SomeClass is a sub-class of SomeOtherClass, then you don't need to cast, you can but you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

No, there shouldn't be a situation where you need to cast `this` to a subclass, at least not with a decent OO design. The below example is just to show how it can be used.

```
class BaseClass {

    public void foo() {
        if(this instanceof SomeClass) {
            SomeClass s = (SomeClass) this;
            s.bar();
        } else {
            baz();
        }
    }

    private void baz() {
        ...
    }
}

class SomeClass extends BaseClass {
    public void bar() {

    }
}
```

Comment: And why would you this?

Comment: Yeah, this seems like something that can be avoided with overridden methods.

Comment: @Turing85: To show the professor that you can cast this.

Comment: @Turing85 No need for it. Clarified it in the answer.